# External stylesheet linking

Tags: html, css

I've been attempting to link my external stylesheet using "../../css/style.css", and it is not properly linking my stylesheets. Keep in mind I am attempting to build a website locally, with all files located in a folder on my desktop(mac).

Here is the current file path for my stylesheets: /Users/btd/Desktop/html:css practice/css/styles.css

Comment: What does your html code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS path should be relative to your HTML file location.

If you HTML file is in  `/Users/btd/Desktop/html:css practice/` and your css is `/Users/btd/Desktop/html:css practice/css/styles.css`

Then the CSS relative path you need to put in the link tag will be: `css/styles.css`

Comment: Okay that worked.  Why do some html templates have ../../ or ../ for the file path? Are the css folders located within other folders?

Comment: For example, if inside your website folder, you have a HTML folder which contains your html templates, and a css folder which contains your css files, to access a css file from a html file, you need to go backward in the path using `..`, so your path will be: `../css/styles.css`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `file.html` on `desktop` folder and have style on `practice/css/styles.css`

- desktop/file.html
- desktop/practice/css/styles.css

the correct link is `href="practice/css/styles.css"`

or other example:

- desktop/practice/file.html
- desktop/practice/css/styles.css

the correct link is `href="css/styles.css"`